# vb6 get data from Class module

Tags: vb6

I'm new in vb6 and not good at searching stuff. what is wrong with this code? I created form1 and inserted class module.

```
Private sub form_load()
 call Jo.Display(txtdate.text)
end sub
```

in may Class module ClsJo

```
public function Display(txtdate as string)
 txtdate = "123abc"
end function
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us what the code is supposed to do and what isn't working.

Comment: i like to get the "123abc" from the ClsJo everytime may form load. tnx

Answer (score 1):

The Display function has one parameter, txtdate, that is passed "by reference", which means that the function may change it's value.  You are passing a value to that function, so I'm assuming you want the txtdate.Text property to contain the value "123abc" after the call.

However, this will not work as you have written it.
txtdate.Text is a property and properties are not really variables, they are kind of functions.  You have "let" operator to set a property value and "get" operator to get the value of the property, but you don't have direct access to the actual variable that stores the value.
Therefore, when passed to the function, VB6 will get the value of the property, create a temporary variable from it and pass that temporary variable as the parameter to the function.  The change in this temporary variable will never find it's way back to the txtdate.Text property.

To get the functionality that I think you want, you can do either one of these:

A. Create a variable yourself, pass that to the function and set the txtDate.Text property to the returned value.  This would be my recommended method, because the function will have cleaner parameters.  Like this:

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()
      Dim myText As String
      myText = txtDate.Text
      call Jo.Display(myText)
      txtDate.Text = myText
   End Sub
```

B:  Pass the txtDate as parameter to the function, instead of the property, like this:

```
Public Sub Display(ByRef dateControl As Object)
   dateControl.Text = "123abc"
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Jo.Display txtDate
End Sub
```